# Java httpUrlconnection get error message when statuscode 500

Tags: java

I'm trying to get error message returns from the server, when status code is **500 Internal server error**.

But when I get `HttpUrlConnection.conn.getErrorStream()` and `HttpUrlConnection.conn.getInputStream()`, both instances fail and throw exception.

Comment: Please provide a minimal executable example that demonstrates your issue.

Comment: You have to look at the server logs. The whole point iof response code 500 is not to leak any informtion about the error to the client.